# resolutionstrategy.force is very slow

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am developing an Android application in which I resolved a dependency problem with gradle using the following addition to my `build.gradle`:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This leads to an enormous build-time increase (from ~15s to ~60s). Is there any way to decrease the build time, for example by resolving the conflict in `JUnit` versions another way? The conflict was introduced by `compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'`, which uses an earlier `JUnit` version.

Answer (score 0):

You may add the `junit` dependency explicitely as a direct dependency, and set `forced = true` on it.

Examples here: http://www.devsbedevin.net/android-understanding-gradle-dependencies-and-resolving-conflicts/